# Counting while mapping to an object in a linq subquery

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq query that uses the let statement from which I derive several subqueries. At the moment, I'm doing 3 subqueries to derive counts using 3 identical joins, and I'm hoping to combine these into one subquery with just one join. I have something like this:

```
let TheFruits = (complex query).ToList(),

Counter1 = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable

             join x in Thefruits on                                                                   
             TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID

             where x.Field1 == 1

             select x).Count(),

Counter2 = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable

             join x in Thefruits on                                                                   
             TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID

             where x.Field2 == 2

             select x).Count(),

Counter3 = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable

             join x in Thefruits on                                                                   
             TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID

             where x.Field3 == 3

             select x).Count(),
```

In order to replace the 3 joins, I want to write something like this but I'm not getting extension methods in the object properties:

```
let TheFruits = (complex query).ToList(),

TheCounterObject = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable

                    join x in Thefruits on                                                                   
                    TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID

                    select new CounterObject()
                    {
                        Count1 = x.Where....Count(),
                        Count2 = x.Where....Count(),
                        Count3 = x.Where....Count(),

                        //not getting .Where extension

                    }).Single()
```

The problem is that I'm not getting the extension methods, just the table columns. In the simple example I'm providing, the .Where clause matches just one condition but in my actual subquery, there are DateTimes and other conditions involved.

How do I run the counts during the object mapping phase?

### Edit

After working on it some more, I now have the following:

```
let TheFruits = (complex query).ToList(),

TheCounterObject = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable

                    join x in TheFruits on                                                                   
                    TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID

                    into TheSubFruits

                    select new CounterObject()
                    {
                        Count1 = TheSubFruits.Where(x.FruitID == TheTable.FruitID && other conditions).Count(),

                        Count2 = TheSubFruits.Where(x.FruitID == TheTable.FruitID && other conditions).Count(),

                        Count3 = TheSubFruits.Where(x.FruitID == TheTable.FruitID && other conditions).Count()
                    }).First()
```

The problem is that the counts are wrong and if I use .Single() instead of .First() I also get a "Sequence Contains More than one Element" error.

Why isn't this subquery returning the same counts than the 3 subqueries? What would I need to change?

Comment: TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID where x.Field2 == 1 || x.Field2 == 2 || x.Field2 == 3

Comment: I think he wants to still count the fruits separately though.

Comment: You could maybe group by the FruitID and then count the amount in each grouping.

Comment: @jdweng: The actual predicate is more complicated and the approach of group by just one condition doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the `.Where` extension on `x` because at that point, x is no longer enumerable. `x` represents each individual fruit but you want to apply the `.Where` to all of them. To do this you could do the join and then perform the counts as I show in the edit.

### Edit

If you need separate counts for separate conditions, I would suggest something like this:

```
var joined = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable
              join x in Thefruits on                                   
              TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID
              select x).ToList();

var count1 = joined.Where(...).Count();
var count2 = joined.Where(...).Count();
var count3 = joined.Where(...).Count();
```

This would allow you to have multiple conditions, the conditions could even overlap and count the same objects if you needed them to. It's very similar to what you originally had but it only performs the join once.

### Edit #2

After thinking about it a bit more, you could do something very similar to what you showed in your second example and combine that with an aggregate to maybe get a result you're looking for.

```cs
var counts = (from TheTable in MyDC.SomeTable
              join x in Thefruits on                                   
              TheTable.FruitID equals x.FruitID
              select new {
                  // Calculate whether this object be included in each count 
                  Count1 = x.FruitId == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                  Count2 = x.FruitId == 2 ? 1 : 0,
                  Count3 = x.FruitId == 3 ? 1 : 0
              }).Aggregate((acc, i) => new {
                  Count1 = acc.Count1 + i.Count1,
                  Count2 = acc.Count2 + i.Count2,
                  Count3 = acc.Count3 + i.Count3
              });
```

Here's a working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W6Bu8e) of this one with the fake data class and now with a join. This might be the closest to what you're looking for as it does the join only once, counts the objects as its doing the mapping, and allows for multiple complex conditions.

Comment: Like I explain in the question, the subquery's .Where clause has a more complicated predicate and can't be grouped

Comment: You could use a more complicated condition within the groupby. Doing that would make the `Key` not very useful, but I've updated my fake example to group only ages greater than 10.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to partition the groups into and if the same condition applies to all of the different counts. If you need separate counts for separate conditions, this will not work.

Comment: I made an edit on the question, added something I tested.

Comment: Have you tried my latest solution? I added a join now to my demo to more closely resemble what you are trying to achieve. The thing that worries me about your new solution is that you're still running the  `.Where` 3 times which is what I thought you were trying to get rid of by doing it in the mapping phase. Running the `.Where...Count()` 3 times means you're still enumerating over the entire joined sub-list 3 times. My new solution only does the enumeration once for as many counts as you want.

Comment: It's the join that I'm looking to avoid repeating 3 times. Haven't tried your solution with .Aggregate but I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: Oh okay then for something simple I would recommend just evaluating the join by calling `toList` and then using that new list from then on like I showed in the first edit.